# Error detected while processing grammarous.vim: E117: Unknown function

Tags: vimscript, plugin-system, functions, error

I am trying to install the vim-grammarous plugin for Vim 8.0.1453. I have cloned the repo into my .vim/plugin directory.

Now every time I open Vim I get an error message which also occurs when I  try to use the plugin.

```
Error detected while processing ~/.vim/plugin/vim-grammarous/autoload/grammarous.vim:
line    4:
E117: Unknown function: vital#grammarous#new
E15: Invalid expression: vital#grammarous#new()
line    5:
E121: Undefined variable: s:V
E15: Invalid expression: s:V.import('Web.XML')
line    6:
E121: Undefined variable: s:V
E15: Invalid expression: s:V.import('OptionParser')
line    7:
E121: Undefined variable: s:V
E15: Invalid expression: s:V.import('Process')
line  501:
E121: Undefined variable: s:O
E15: Invalid expression: s:O.new().on('--lang=VALUE', 'language to check', 
  {'default' : g:grammarous#default_lang}).on('--[no-]preview',  
   'enable auto preview', {'default' : 1}).on('--[no-]comments-only',  
   'check comment only',  {'default' : ''}).on('--[no-]move-to-first-error', 
   'move to first error', {'default' : g:grammarous#move_to_first_error}).on('--
    reinstall-languagetool',   'reinstall LanguageTool', {'default' : 0})
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How can I get vim-grammarous to work?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.vim/plugin` directory is *not* where you want to unpack your plug-ins! (Yes, I known the name would suggest so...)

If you want to use Vim 8 packages (which I believe you do), then you should unpack it under a directory named `~/.vim/pack/*/start`, where the component after `pack` can be named anything (suggestions are `bundle`, `vendor` or your username.)

---

See [`:help packages`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#packages) for more information about Vim packages.

One alternative to Vim packages is to use a Vim plug-in manager to manage your plug-ins (they can load, install and update them.) If you decide to use a plug-in manager, I'd recommend [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug), which is simple to install (just download a single file), to configure and to use.

---

About the `~/.vim/plugin` directory, that's a much simpler concept of plug-in and it simply includes Vim script files that are *always unconditionally* loaded by Vim on startup.

As Vim evolved, the need for Vim scripts that would loaded in different situations arose, and new directories were added for:

- dynamically loaded Vim scripts, loaded when a function in that namespace is first called (`autoload`)
- scripts that are loaded for files of specific types, for example code in specific languages (`ftplugin`)
- scripts to detect what the type of a file should be, based on its extension or even file contents (`ftdetect`)
- scripts implementing syntax highlighting (`syntax`) or indentation (`indent`) for a specific file type.

A "modern" Vim plug-in is in fact a package that will typically include Vim scripts split into one or more of these directories. (In fact, a large part of plug-ins will not even ship anything in the `plugin` directory, which means they typically don't incur any cost at Vim startup and only get loaded when they're used, either through a filetype or when an autoloaded function is invoked.)

Since the term `plugin` was already used, Vim 8 decided to call these "packages", but of course the common term for those is still a "Vim plug-in," which unfortunately causes this confusion.

Comment: I have more resources on the differences [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20980/10604) and [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/17482/10604)